# Dates Falls Within a Range

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I would like to count the number of records which is within a given date range. These two records should be counted in the derived field Year_1985. I can't figure out how to make sure that these dates fall within the specified range. AD_Start_Date and AD_End_Date are both DATE fields in my table.

Record 1 (Should be counted in Year_1985, Year_1986, Year_1987):
AD_Start_Date = '01/30/1980'
AD_End_Date = '07/01/1990'

Record 2 (Should be counted in Year_1985 only):
AD_Start_Date = '03/30/1985'
AD_End_Date = '07/01/1985'

Record 3  (Should be counted in Year_1985, Year_1986, Year_1987)
AD_Start_Date = '02/01/1978'
AD_End_Date = '07/01/1990'

Record 4  (Should be counted in Year_1986, Year_1987)
AD_Start_Date = '05/01/1986'
AD_End_Date = '11/30/1987'

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN to_char(AD_Start_Date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') <= '12/31/1985' AND 
 to_char(AD_End_Date, 
'MM/DD/YYYY') >= '01/01/1985' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Year_1985

,SUM(CASE WHEN to_char(AD_Start_Date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') <= '12/31/1986' AND 
to_char(AD_End_Date, 
'MM/DD/YYYY') >= '01/01/1986' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Year_1986

,SUM(CASE WHEN to_char(AD_Start_Date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') <= '12/31/1987' AND 
to_char(AD_End_Date, 
'MM/DD/YYYY') >= '01/01/1987' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Year_1987
```

Comment: Don't convert to character.  When compared as strings, your format will compare the month first, so all the Januarys will be together, in order by year, then the Februarys.  Do it as dates, and use the "BETWEEN" operator.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please give me an example of this?

Comment: Add more record with different dates and expected output for better understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming that query you posted *should* return desired result, modify it so that you compare **dates**, not strings (which is what you're doing).

For example:

```
select
sum(case when ad_start_date <= date '1985-12-31' and 
              ad_end_date   >= date '1985-01-01' then 1 else 0 end) as year_1985,
...
```

---

I used date literals which always consist of the `date` keyword and date value enclosed into single quotes in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

You could also try with `to_date` function whose first parameter represents date value, while the second one *reflects* that value's format, e.g.
`to_date('31.12.1985', 'dd.mm.yyyy')`.

---

**[EDIT]**, after you posted some more info.

Conditional aggregation it is, just a little bit different from what you did. If I understood you correctly, with sample data

```
SQL> with test (id, ad_start_date, ad_end_Date) as
  2    (select 1, date '1980-01-30', date '1990-07-01' from dual union all -- 1985, 1986, 1987
  3     select 2, date '1985-03-30', date '1985-07-01' from dual union all -- 1985
  4     select 3, date '1978-02-01', date '1990-07-01' from dual union all -- 1985, 1986, 1987
  5     select 4, date '1986-05-01', date '1987-11-30' from dual           --       1986, 1987
  6    )
```

Query looks like this; accidentally, **all** years (1985, 1986 and 1987 have the same resulting value: `3`:

```
  7  select
  8    sum(case when 1985 between extract(year from ad_start_date) and
  9                               extract(year from ad_end_date) then 1 else 0 end) year_1985,
 10    sum(case when 1986 between extract(year from ad_start_date) and
 11                               extract(year from ad_end_date) then 1 else 0 end) year_1986,
 12    sum(case when 1987 between extract(year from ad_start_date) and
 13                               extract(year from ad_end_date) then 1 else 0 end) year_1987
 14  from test;

 YEAR_1985  YEAR_1986  YEAR_1987
---------- ---------- ----------
         3          3          3

SQL>
```

Comment: I would probably use the YEAR function and just compare to 1985, 1986, etc. Doesn’t affect the logic but would make the code easier to understand

Comment: You wouldn't, @Nick. There's no such function in Oracle :) But yes - I got your point. You could e.g. `extract(year from ad_start_date)` or `to_char(ad_start_date, 'yyyy')`. Though, I'm not sure what "Record 1" and "Record 2" mentioned in question represent; as if "year" in that example isn't full calendar year (from 1st of January to 31st of December), but something like fiscal year (which lasts from e.g. 1st of April to 31st of March next year). If not, then I agree - your suggestion makes perfect sense.

Comment: I'm not sure that the logic is correct for the start and end dates.  Wondering if you wouldn't mind reviewing that?

Comment: Could you post several sample rows which illustrate the problem? What is that table description? Which column does it contain, and which datatype did you use? It is a simple task to decide whether certain date falls between two other dates, but - you used two columns AD_START_DATE and AD_END_DATE. What do they represent? It isn't obvious, so I believe that sample data might help us help you.

Comment: I added a few more examples. Thank you

Comment: Also a great solution and easier to read than mine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BETWEEN` :-

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN ('01-JAN-1985' BETWEEN AD_Start_Date   AND AD_End_Date 
           OR '31-DEC-1985' BETWEEN AD_Start_Date   AND AD_End_Date ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Year_1985
```

Comment: This is a great solution. Much easier to read than mine. Thanks

Comment: Please make correct as answer if it is solved your problem.

Comment: This is not a great solution, because `'01-JAN-1985' BETWEEN '01-FEB-1990' AND '31-JAN-1999'` will evaluate "true". You can't use strings.